# How do you notate the use of an effect pedal? What precedents are there?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, effects-pedal

In my WIP, the first two phrases don't ask for any effects, and the third measure onwards requires a Leslie simulator to be switched on (and as to why I'm being so specific for this piece, it is because only one person, whose gear I know, will ever see this sheet). How do I notate this?

In general, has anyone in the last half-century or so had any word on what a standard for notation of use of effects units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just write it! It's the same as **Fans on** and **Fans off** in a vibraphone part. You can write it above the stave, or between the staves if the part is written using two. Synths usually have presets marked the same way: **Preset 12**, or **Patch 133**, or **Didgeridoo patch** or whatever.

I put such instructions in a box, like the one you draw around beaters in a percussion part.

You don't put **senza sord.** at the beginning of any orchestral part because the default state for all instruments IS unmuted. But the default state of e.g. a Hammond B3 may be **Leslie on**. So, as a precaution, you might put **Leslie off** at the start of the part.

(I don't understand what you mean about being specific btw.)

Comment: For a funny note, I'm actually using a Leslie sim on an electric piano. The default state is not using a Leslie :)

Comment: Confirm - default Leslie is **off** - the horn and baffle may be turning slowly, but there's no Doppler effect until it's switched **on**. On gtr. parts, there may be 'chorus', or 'dist.' just written in.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I played one quite a lot in the early 80's. Lovely things. But I still think one would write 'Leslie off' at the start. If its characteristic sound is 'Leslie on' then maybe that's its default. I suppose it depends how you define 'default state'. (Or whether you bother!) Is there a default on/off state for the vibe's fans? Its characteristic sound is 'on'. And has it got a default fan-speed? A snare drum's characteristic sound is 'snares on' but they get packed away with snares off. Hmm. I'm abandoning this :-)

Comment: My reasoning is that with a joystick on a lot of keyboards, not touchng it results in Leslie off, and moving it gives Leslie on. Same with the pedals I use with keyboards (expression, of course!). With snare drum it can't be a snare drum *without* the snare! So default is *ON*. Needs notating if it has to be off. And good drummers leave it off till playng. Bit like mics?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in scores for musicals in bass or guitar parts, but it's usually very low detail. Usually there will just be a short note like "(fuzz)" or "(wah)" above or below the staff.